# Export SQL result to csv through sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, export-to-csv, sp-send-dbmail

I am trying to create a Job that sends SQL result as a CSV attachment via email.
I manage to do it through the following code:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'main',  
@recipients = 'test@email.com',  
@body = 'test',
@query = 'SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM DB.dbo.Table',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'Test.csv',
@query_result_header = 1,
@query_result_width = 256,
@query_result_separator = ',',
@exclude_query_output = 1,
@append_query_error = 1,
@query_no_truncate = 0,
@query_result_no_padding = 1,
@subject = 'Test';
```

However, I have 2 problems:

- They are all in one column separated by comma instead of 3 columns.
- There is an extra row after the column header that contains dashes.

**Current CSV File:**

[image]

**Desired CSV File:**

[image]

Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just found an answer to my own question.

Apparently, I have to insert a new row in the top of the file containing “sep=,”. This forces Excel to understand that it is a comma delimited file, and ensures that it will open correctly.

You can alter the name of the first column to include this header text. We simply rename “Column1” to “sep=,{CR}{LF}Column1”. Then when dbmail prints out the column headers in the file, the Column1 name will be split on two lines, preceeded by “sep=,”.

Excel treats this first row as an instruction and does not display it, just uses it to make sure it formats the data correctly.

Full Details here: https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2014/04/excel-doesnt-open-csv-files-correctly-from-sp_send_dbmail/

Answer (score 0):

USE "SET NOCOUNT ON" with two query's to solve this problem.
the first query is the headers.
the second query is the result.
example:

```
@query = 'SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT ''COLUMN NAME 1'', ''COLUMN NAME 2'', ''COLUMN NAME3''
SELECT P.PRODUCT, P.PRICE, P.TYPE
FROM PRODUCTS P'
```